# My Fragment appears underneath the Toolbar regardless of how I change constraints

Tags: android, kotlin, toolbar

No matter how I add constraints, nothing changes in terms of my Fragment which contains a RecyclerView.

I have added a toolbar:

***OnCreate* in MainActivity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)//TODO find inconsistencies
    val demo = DemoDataBuilder()


    // Set the toolbar as support action bar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    // Now get the support action bar
    val actionBar = supportActionBar

    // Set toolbar title/app title
    actionBar!!.title = "AwezaMed"

    // Set action bar/toolbar sub title
    actionBar.subtitle = "App subtitle"

    // Set action bar elevation
    actionBar.elevation = 4.0F

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp)
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { _ -> onBackPressed()}

    startCategoryHome(savedInstanceState)

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/root_layout">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="57dp"
    android:padding="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:subtitleTextColor="#f5fbff"
    app:titleTextColor="#fff" />


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/categoyList_fragment"
    android:name="za.co.aweza.awezamediphrases.fragments.CategoryListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_hcp_category" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You'll notice that in the layout code above, I have a very farfetched constraint that I tried to use.

Here is how it appears in designView:
[image]

But regardless of anything I try, the first cell of the RV in the Fragment sits mostly underneath the toolbar. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try switching the order of the elements in the layout XML?

Comment: Yes. No difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of fragment put this in your xml:

```
`<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />`
```

Replace the frame layout  with any fragment you want using this function:

```
 ` fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout_fragment_container, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

@EliodeBeirut's answer worked, but I found that changing the layout activity_main.xml from Constraint layout to Linear Layout worked as well.